# How do I find a base of orthogonal complement $U^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let U be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$, which is through $(1,2,3,-1,2)^T$ and $(1,0,-1,0,1)^T$ spanned.

Okay I know what those vectors need to be:
$x+y+3z-t+v=0$

$x-z+v=0$

But still I don't know how  to from these make three vectors. If someone could help I would be thank ful :)

Comment: The first equation should be $x+2y+3z-t+v=0$. Also, you now have a system of equations. Find the general solution and use that to find three independent solutions, they form a basis for the orthogonal complement.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, you're looking for precisely the vectors $(x,y,z,t,v)$ which satisfy $x+y+3z-t+v=0$ and $x-z+v=0$. You can write this system in the form $Ax=0$, and use Gaussian elimination to find all solutions.